# Submit form using curl in php

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to submit a form using curl in PHP. is there any web to get the name of fields on target URL so that I can map them to my fields. Below is my code, I am using for curl:

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="name" >
<input type="text" name="email">
<input type="submit" name ="create_account">
</form>


<?php
 if(isset($_POST['create_account'])){
 $name =    $_POST['name'];
 $email = $_POST['email'];
 $url = "www.exampleurl.com"; // Where you want to post data
 try {
  $ch = curl_init();

  if (FALSE === $ch)
     throw new Exception('failed to initialize');

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);  // Tell cURL you want to post something
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "name=". $name ."&email=". $email); 
   // Define what you want to post
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  //curl_setopt(/* ... */);
  $content = curl_exec($ch);
  $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
  $json = json_decode($content, true);
   if (FALSE === $content)
    throw new Exception(curl_error($ch), curl_errno($ch));

  } catch(Exception $e) {

   trigger_error(sprintf(
     'Curl failed with error #%d: %s',
     $e->getCode(), $e->getMessage()),
     E_USER_ERROR);
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: What is error you get?

Comment: I am unable to map my fields to target URL fields

Comment: Mapping is done with `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`, should work. Are you sure that url that display html form is same as one submited (action parameter in form tag)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$data = array('name'=>$name, 'email'=>$email);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
```

From php5 upwards, usage of [http_build_query](https://php.net/http_build_query) is recommended.

Before php5 you could perform urlencode() to each var value.